# What does SNMP holding time do, and how does it do it?

Tags: snmp

I'm finding statements about SNMP holding-time like "traps whose holding time expires are deleted." While that COULD be written less usefully, it would take significant effort.

I'm assuming that it doesn't work exactly as described, else setting any holding time would delete all traps the moment that time passes.

I'm not seeing how this--as described--does anything but keep any and all traps from ever being sent. So what does holding time actually do, and how does it do it?

Comment: Where did you find that statement? I'm aware of at least two different meanings for SNMP trap hold time.

Comment: H3C's switch guide: http://www.h3c.com/portal/Technical_Support___Documents/Technical_Documents/Switches/H3C_S5120_Series_Switches/Configuration/Operation_Manual/H3C_S5120-SI_CG-Release_1101-6W105/201108/723598_1285_0.htm

Comment: HP 6600 router guide:
http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/kb/docDisplay?javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.prp_ba847bafb2a2d782fcbb0710b053ce01=wsrp-navigationalState%3DdocId%253Demr_na-c03128012-1%257CdocLocale%253D%257CcalledBy%253D&javax.portlet.tpst=ba847bafb2a2d782fcbb0710b053ce01&ac.admitted=1410559971760.876444892.199480143

Comment: Cisco WLC 7.6 guide (sort of): http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/controller/7-6/configuration-guide/b_cg76/b_cg76_chapter_0111.html

Comment: 3 examples there. Wouldn't mind knowing both meanings for it.